# I want to make an if statement when an image tap to be full screen

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer

here is the code that I check if they images are tapped but only the 3 image is apply full screen.

```
 func imageTapped() {
  let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageZoom(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    if detailsImage[0].isUserInteractionEnabled == false {
        detailsImage[0].isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        detailsImage[0].addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        self.statusImageView = detailsImage[0]
    }
    let tapGestureRecognizer1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageZoom(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
        detailsImage[1].isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        detailsImage[1].addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer1)
        self.statusImageView = detailsImage[1]
    let tapGestureRecognizer2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageZoom(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
        detailsImage[2].isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        detailsImage[2].addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer2)
        self.statusImageView = detailsImage[2]
 
}
```

it is any who can help me?

Comment: So you want to open the zoomed image on the tap gesture for each of the three images?

Comment: Yes. That is working but only for the detailsImage[2], Even I tapped detailsImage[1] again detailsImage[2] open full screen. How I will make it for each image?

Comment: What is `self.statusImageView `, an `UIImageView`? Can you post your full class code? Looks like you are overriding `self.statusImageView ` multiple times, so it takes only the last image view changes (in this case `detailsImage[2]`).

Comment: here is the full codehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/65916472/i-want-to-make-if-statement-so-each-image-will-be-full-screen-when-the-user-tsp